# How to add new header to jersey client to upload multipart file

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs

Please find below jersey client code to upload multipart file:

```
String url = "http://localhost:7070"
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webresource = client.resource(url);
File file = new File("C://Data//image1.jpg");
File thumbnail = new File("C://Data/image2.jpg");


InputStream isthumbnail = new FileInputStream(thumbnail);
InputStream isfile = new FileInputStream(file);

FormDataMultiPart multiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();
FormDataBodyPart bodyPart1 = new FormDataBodyPart(FormDataContentDisposition.name("Thumbnail").fileName("thumbnail").build(), isthumbnail, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
FormDataBodyPart bodyPart2 = new FormDataBodyPart(FormDataContentDisposition.name("File").fileName("file").build(), isfile, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
multiPart.bodyPart(bodyPart);
multiPart.bodyPart(bodyPart1);

//New Headers
String fileContentLength = "form-data; contentLength=\""+Long.toString(file.length())+ "\"";
String thumbnailContentLength = "form-data; contentLength=\""+Long.toString(file.length())+ "\"";

final ClientResponse clientResp = webresource.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).post(ClientResponse.class, multiPart);
System.out.println("File Upload Success with Response"+clientResp.getStatus());
```

I need to add the String fileContentLength and thumbnailContentLength as header 
Content-Length.
How do i add the headers as part of multipart and post the request?Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`FormDataContentDisposition`](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/FormDataContentDisposition.html) as an argument to [`FormDataBodyPart(FormDataContentDisposition formDataContentDisposition, Object entity, MediaType mediaType)`](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/FormDataBodyPart.html#FormDataBodyPart(org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition,%20java.lang.Object,%20javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType)).

```
final FormDataMultiPart formDataMultiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();
final String value = "Hello World";
final FormDataContentDisposition dispo = FormDataContentDisposition
        .name("file")
        .fileName("test.txt")
        .size(value.getBytes().length)
        .build();
final FormDataBodyPart bodyPart = new FormDataBodyPart(dispo, value);
formDataMultiPart.bodyPart(bodyPart);
```

Comment: So adding the .size gives me something like that for the dispo { form-data; "filename="test.txt"; size=31; name="file" }. I had to do bodyPart.getHeaders().add("Content-Length", String.valueOf(value.getBytes().length));